# calling an method in a view controller from a child view

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

In my ViewController I have created a view which contains a button and a bunch of other elements.  When the button is pressed I want to call a method from the parent ViewController.  I tried:

```
[self.superview buttonPressedMethod];
```

But the superview is no the ViewController but UIView.  Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what the target/action mechanism is for. Make the method in the view controller an IBAction. Set the view controller as the button's target, and set the method as its action. That should be all you need to do.

Comment: The button is created programmatically.  What would the ViewController's target?

Comment: The view controller doesn't have a target, it *is* the target. You can set the button's target and action using `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`. Specify the view controller as the target and the method you want to call as the action. Note that the method will have to have an appropriate signature. Have you read [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html)?

Comment: Yeah sorry I quickly wrote my response.  I understand that the ViewController is my target.  What I meant is how do I set the ViewController as the target programmatically? For instance I set self as the target here: **[forwardButton addTarget:self action:@selector(forwardButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];** how do I make that the view controller instead?

Comment: What is `self` in that code snippet? Normally, if a view is created programmatically, it's the view controller that creates it. If that's not the case here, then you have to ask yourself: *Why is something other than the view controller creating this button?*, and *Why does the thing creating the button not know about the view controller?*, and *Should I think about refactoring this code?*

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks for your help.  I was trying to be clever and reset the target later in my code.  But when I reset it `self.superview` was no longer my ViewController which is what I was hoping. Thanks again

Comment: `self.superview` could never be your view controller -- a superview is the containing view, while a view controller is not a view at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
At ParentViewController.h 
-(void)ParentMethod;

At ParentViewController.m
-(IBAction)button:(id)sender {
       [self ParentMethod];
}

At IBAction of Play Button on child view controller do this:
-(IBAction)ChildMethod:(id)sender {
       ParentViewController *parent=self.parentViewController;
       [parent ParentMethod];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better create delegate in view controller and set delegate in child view, so when something occur call delegate method according to it.